# current timestamp generation in php and updating in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

i want to create a timestamp by which i can know which post is modified when and all. in mysql databse, i made a coloumn called lastmodified, with type as timestamp. now, when i am updating the data in db, i want to update the current timestamp in last modified. how to do so? also could anyone please tell me, if any function exits for comparing these timestamps.

```
$now = time();

$query = "update storydb set lastmodified = '$now' where story_id = '$story_id'";
mysqli_query($con, $query);
```

Comment: Please don't re-engine the wheel. Use mysql now() instead of your var for datetime ;) set lastmodified = now()

Comment: just change the attribute of your column to `on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and everytime somethings updates on that row..the timestamp will automatically changed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[time()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) returns UNIX Timetamp in integer format e.g. `1223485636`.

You want it in `2014-12-10 02:02:36`

Use MySQL [now()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) function instead of `$now`

```
$query = "update storydb set lastmodified = now() where story_id = '$story_id'";
```

`now()` is a MySQL function that returns current Time Stamp (including date).

Answer (score 2):

No, its not unix timestamp that should be used in there, just a normal `NOW()` should suffice:

```
$query = "UPDATE storydb SET lastmodified = NOW() WHERE story_id = ?";
$update = $con->prepare($query);
$update->bind_param('s', $story_id);
$update->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

To insert current unix timestamp in data base

```
$time = time();
$qry = 'update db_name' set column_name = $time where condition;
mysql_query($qry);
```